# How to change content-type from plain/text to xml on external webserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to write a server status checker for some game servers of a Mount & Blade: Warband mod I play, and I'm having some issues. When I go to the ip addresses of the servers in my browser, they appear to display server status details in XML format. However, the URL does not have any file extension, as it is just an IP address with a port on the end of it. If I copy and save the text I see going to the IP in a browser and save it as a .xml file on my laptop, it displays fine with my script. However, if I try to query the IP address directly and not from the local file, it doesn't work. I checked the IP address page and it appears that the server details are being displayed as plain/text and not text/xml, hence why the script isn't working.

Is there anyway to change a content type/MIME type on my own webserver so that incoming plain texts data is interpreted as XML? If yes, how would I do that?
Or is there something I can change with the script that would get things working?

Here's the script I have:
http://pastebin.com/vWb8sfBm

Comment: So you're proxying the request on your own server anyway? Then it should be trivial to rewrite the header.

Comment: The IP address I'm querying is separate from my web server, plus the I do not own or manage the IP address I'm querying.

Comment: The problem is the server doesn't declare the document to be XML. There's no XML declaration tag at the top of the page. I'd start by contacting the owner of the server and ask them if they can correct that error. Or if the script is produced by the mod, contact the owner of the mod.

Comment: Just out of interest, what happens if you try `xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' + xmlloadXMLDoc("http://69.64.32.90:8044");`?

Comment: @Styphon Tried that, but it returns a unexpected T_STRING syntax error. Just returns the error on line 22, but it doesn't specify which column. Probably some error with quotations somewhere, but I can't seem to find it

Comment: Unexpected T_STRING? That's a PHP error. Everything you've posted is JavaScript and what I posted above is JavaScript. I assume what you posted in pastebin is you ***actual*** code. If not you need to post the relevant code.

Comment: @Styphon: Isn't `xmlloadXMLDoc` an async action usually? @user1087074: You should post the relevant code in your question, not somewhere else on the internet. Please [edit] it in.

Comment: @Bergi `loadXMLDoc` is a custom function he wrote. But it is async, yes... your point?

Comment: @Styphon: If it's async, then `xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' + xmlloadXMLDoc("http://69.64.32.90:8044");` cannot work